# Spark work scheduling

Tags: apache-spark

The scenario: A large collection of objects in an RDD, then an expensive map function, followed by a collect.

The map function takes a varying amount of time.

I assume the partitions are initially evenly distributed among the workers.

What happens if one worker happens to get a lot of the slower partitions, will the other nodes pick up partitions from the over-worked node?

Comment: Probably only if speculative execution is enabled (it is disabled by default) - see `spark.speculation` in [configuration page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/configuration.html) of the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn speculation ON to solve this problem. You could look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HG2Yd-3r4-M from minute 34 to minute 56 for deep understanding how it works.

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do